# Why is this mongo sort not working in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm following an example from the PHP docs to sort some records in a collection:

```
    $cursor = $mongo->party_scores->find()->limit(10);
    $cursor = $cursor->sort(array("score",-1));
    foreach($cursor as $doc) {
        print_r($doc);
    }
```

Doing this, I see the documents in a random order (not sorted).

But executing this query from the mongo console produces a correctly sorted response:

```
db.party_scores.find().sort({score : -1 })
```

I feel like there must be something obvious I'm missing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I see the problem. Instead of doing this:

```
$cursor->sort(array("score",-1))
```

Try this:

```
$cursor->sort(array("score" => -1))
```

Easy mistake to make, but very frustrating to find if you don't see it right away.

Comment: That appears to have been it, thanks. I probably would have stared at it for another hour without seeing it.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::sort() ? What is the error?