# sorting Mongodb cursor does not seem to work

Tags: php, mongodb, sorting

So I want to retrieve a bunch of products from a MongoDB sorted by a field called rating, which is a numeric field.

For this I do:

```
$cursor = $this->productCollection->find();
$cursor->sort(array("rating" => -1));
```

However when I loop the cursor and print the rating:

```
foreach ($cursor as $id => $product)
{
   echo "<br>". $product['rating'];
}
```

I do not get the rating in sorted order, I get values like:

```
1.2
3.1
1.1
2.0
2.1
4.2
3.7
```

What should I do to get the results sorted correctly?

Comment: are you sure that it is really a number, and not a number represented as a string.

Comment: It is a number, the JSON shows the ratings without quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to re-assign your cursor before your loop through:

```
$cursor = $cursor->sort(array("rating" => -1));
```

Otherwise you are just iterating through the non-sorted original cursor. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199015/why-is-this-mongo-sort-not-working-in-php).